# how do i get my calculation app to work using variables instead of state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I had a functioning ebay fee calculator app and I was using state to collect and calculate the values from the text input fields but I ran into some errors because I was using set state in the `render()` so I was advised on stackoverflow to change to using just let and const no state however now im left with a bunch of code that I'm not sure what to change/keep to get my app working again it would be a huge help if an experienced dev could help me with this being that I'm a real noob

```
render() {
        let soldPrice = 0;
        let shippingCost = 0;
        let shippingCharge = 0;
        let itemCost = 0;
        let profit = ' ';
        const paypalFee = 0.30;
        const paypalFeePercentage = 0.029;
        const ebayFee = 0.1;


          soldPrice += shippingCharge;

          const calculation = soldPrice - soldPrice * paypalFeePercentage -
          paypalFee
          - soldPrice * ebayFee - shippingCost
          - itemCost;

          const roundedNumber = calculation.toPrecision(i);

       return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
         <NumberInput
         value={shippingCharge}
         />

         <NumberInput
         onchange={(shippingCost) => this.setState({ shippingCost })}

         <NumberInput
```

// I used this to change the value of item cost state when the user filled out the input for how much the item costed them to buy but im not sure how to update the variables onChange

```
         onchange={(itemCost) => this.setState({ itemCost })}
         />

         <<NumberInput
         onchange={(itemCost) => this.setState({ itemCost })}
         />

         <NumberInput
         onchange={(itemCost) => this.setState({ itemCost })}
         />
          TOTAL PROFIT:{roundedNumber}</Text>

          <TouchableOpacity
```

also trying to figure out how to calculate the profit when the user clickes the calculate button

```
          onPress={this.calculateProfit}
          >
             <Text>Calculate </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
     );
     }
    }
my numberinput component

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

    export default class NumberInput extends Component {

     render() {
    return (

      <TextInput
          keyboardType={'numeric'}
          onChangeText={this.props.onchange}
          value={this.props.value}
      />

    );
     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As `NumberInput` is your custom component and you are passing `onchange` as `props`,

```
<NumberInput onchange={(shippingCost) => this.setState({ shippingCost })}
```

From `NumberInput` component you should call `onchange` like this,

```
<TextInput
     keyboardType={'numeric'}
     onChangeText={(value) => this.props.onchange(value)}
     value={this.props.value}
/>
```

Also you using values from state in incorrect way,

```
const calculation = soldPrice - soldPrice * paypalFeePercentage -
          paypalFee
          - soldPrice * ebayFee - shippingCost
          - itemCost;
```

You should use values from state using `this.state` like,

```
const calculation = soldPrice - soldPrice * paypalFeePercentage -
          paypalFee
          - soldPrice * ebayFee - this.state.shippingCost
          - this.state.itemCost;
```

**Note:** As of now I can see only `shippingCost` and `itemCost` in a state, if you have more values in state, you should use them the same way using `this.state`.

Comment: but i'm trying to make it work using variables only not using state as suggested by another dev from stack overflow as that could potentially cause errors

Comment: You cannot access state variable's without using `this.state`. You have to use like this only. This is the only way of accessing variable's from state and there is no harm in that. It will not create any issue/errors.

Comment: Probably you are talking about `this.setState()` in `render()` function. So yes, we should not set state in `render()` function, but we can definitely access the state.

Comment: its not calculating the profit properly like it was before not sure whats wrong with it

Comment: For this you need to debug the code, check out your formula is correct and getting correct values from state.

Comment: do you have any suggestion as to how i should call the calculation function when the user clicks the calculation button because the way i'm doing it doesent seem to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197848/discussion-between-prog-and-ravibagul91).